# how can Unify 3 different c++ main file in 1 file

Tags: c++

im new in c++.i have code 3 different shape(sun-tree-flower) in 3 different main function.i want to unify them in one shape.but i cant call more than one main function per file.how can do that.my code's below

> ```
> sun:
> ```

```
#include <stdio.h>

void drawCircle(int r)
{

    int N = 2*r+1;

    int x, y; 


    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
        {

            x = i-r;
            y = j-r;


            if (x*x + y*y <= r*r+1 )
                printf(".");
            else 
                printf(" ");
            printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    drawCircle(8);
    return 0;
}
```

> tree :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
cout<<"Rasme drakht ba c++"<<endl;
int a=15,x,b,p=0;
for(b=1; b<=a; b++)
{
p++;
for(int i=0;i<=p;i++)
{
for(x=2*a-1-i;x>=b;x--)
{
cout<<" ";
}
if(b+i<a)
{
for(int x=1;x<=b+i;x++)

{
cout<<". ";
}
cout<<endl;
}
else
goto end;
}
}
end:
p=0;
for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
{
for(int j=12+p;j>=1;j--)
{
cout<<" ";
}
p=a;
for(int k=0;k<3;k++)
{
cout<<"| ";
}
cout<<endl;
}
}
```

> folwer:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t;
 printf("\n\n\n\n\n");

 for(i=0;i<15;i++)
 printf(" ");
 printf(".         .\n");

 for(j=0;j<13;j++)
 printf(" ");
 printf(".   .     .   .\n");

 for(k=0;k<11;k++)
 printf(" ");
 printf(".      .   .      .\n");

 for(l=0;l<11;l++)
 printf(" ");
 printf(".       . .       .\n");

 for(m=0;m<11;m++)
 printf(" ");
 printf(".        .        .\n");

 for(n=0;n<11;n++)
 printf(" ");
 printf(".                 .\n");

 for(o=0;o<12;o++)
 printf(" ");
 printf(".               .\n"); 

 for(p=0;p<13;p++)
 printf(" ");
 printf(".             .\n");

 for(q=0;q<14;q++)
 printf(" ");
 printf(".           .\n");

 for(r=0;r<15;r++)
 printf(" ");
 printf(".         .\n");

 for(s=0;s<17;s++)
 printf(" ");
 printf(".     .\n");

 for(t=0;t<20;t++)
  printf("");
  printf("                   | | \n");
  printf("                   | | \n");
  printf("                   | | \n");
  printf("                   | | \n");
  printf("                   | | \n");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do what you did with `drawCircle` and put the other drawing code into separate functions. Then call all three from a single `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Use all this function in one main.

Or better, сreate a classes for these objects.

Answer (score 0):

You should:

1. Create three separate classes for these objects.
2. Instantiate these classes in your main file.
3. Call functions you need in your main

Answer (score 0):

Create those three as subprograms and call those from the main, all in the same project